# MySQL user account 'From Host' setting

Tags: mysql

I've just installed Wamp server 2 and I get the following 4 default MySQL users:

```
    USER         FROM HOST
    <anonymous>  localhost
    root         localhost
    root         127.0.0.1
    root         ::1
```

What does the ::1 mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is the new way to express [home based on the IPv6 protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6). It's new to me as well.

By this, my guess is your WAMP installed MySQL 5.5.

Just remember two things

1. [There is no place like 127.0.0.1](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/generic/5d6a/)
2. [There is no place like ::1](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/frustrations/691f/)